# tippecanoe Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, colors, mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles

I have some geoJSON with millions of points, which I convert to mbtiles using tippecanoe. I upload this mbtiles file to mapbox, add the tiles to a style, and I can see my data using mapbox gl JS. How can I style the points so they appear as points with certain colors. I add marker-color and marker-symbol to the geoJSON, and I can then see these if I console.log a clicked feature. However, these aren't working. For shape, I just want simple circles, as is the default. But I need to have the color of these circles custom based on values set in the geoJSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up deciding on using this tile server and hosting the tiles myself : https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php. The example code the server gives you after loading an mbtile file should work, except that the type in the layer style json should be changed to circle instead of line if your data consists of circles, see this : https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/250#issuecomment-220871181